# CakePHP can't load third-party tools from Vendor

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.8.3 with PHP 5.4 Centos 7
I am using this KoolSuite third party PHP UI tool to generate grids,menu tabs
But when i try to include it in my view helper It's not loading and in inspect element console I am getting this notice:
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://cake.cei.org/app/Vendor/KoolSuite/KoolTabs/styles/hay/hay.css"

Controller:
app/Controller/userscontroller.php

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController
{

    var $helpers = array('Form','Kooltabinclude');
    public $uses = array('User', 'CurrencyConversion', 'Asset');
    public $components = array('ValidateUser');
    var $name = 'Users';

    public function dashboard(){}
}
?>
```

View:
app/View/users/dashboard.ctp

```
<?
// Render Kool Tabs using Kooltabinclude helper
echo $this->Kooltabinclude->tab_include("dashboard", "");
?>
```

Helper:
app/View/Helper/KooltabincludeHelper.php

```
<?php
   App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');

  class KooltabincludeHelper extends AppHelper
  {
    function tab_include($tabs, $active_tab, $sub_active_tab = NULL)
    {
      App::import('Vendor', 'KoolSuite/KoolTabs', array('file' => 'KoolSuite/KoolTabs/kooltabs.php'));

      $kts = new KoolTabs("kts");
      $koolpath = "Vendor/KoolSuite";
      $kts->styleFolder = "$koolpath/KoolTabs/styles/hay";
    }
  }
?>
```

.vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *>

    DocumentRoot /home/webroot/cake.cei.org/htdocs
    ServerName cake.cei.org

    <IfModule mod_security.c>
        SecRuleEngine Off
        SecRuleInheritance Off
        SecFilterScanPOST Off
        SecRequestBodyAccess Off
    </IfModule>

<Directory /home/webroot/cake.cei.org/htdocs>

        FileETag MTime Size

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                  RewriteEngine on
                  RewriteRule    Vendor(.*) Vendor$1 [L]
                  RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
                  RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
        </IfModule>

        #this is for full functionality in .htaccess. Remove if not needed.

        AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /home/webroot/cake.cei.org/htdocs/app>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
        RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
     </IfModule>
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /home/webroot/cake.cei.org/htdocs/app/webroot>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
        AllowOverride None

</Directory>

    ErrorLog /home/webroot/cake.cei.org/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /home/webroot/cake.cei.org/logs/access_log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `App::import('Vendor', ...)` calls need to use dot syntax for plugins. See [this](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/2.x/Lib/IcalLib.php) for an example.

Comment: Hi mark, so should i do App::import('Vendor', 'KoolSuite.KoolTabs', array('file' => 'KoolSuite/KoolTabs/kooltabs.php'));

Comment: Find out where the files are in my plugin and replicate, this should solve it.